# Unable to reference .netstandard 2.0 project in core 2.0 project

Tags: .net, resharper, visual-studio-2017

I'm a little bit puzzled as I'm unable to add .netstandard 2.0 project into core 2.0 one. I also tried with adding multiple target frameworks but this did not work either. Please take a look at the image attached.

Ps. I have updated to VS 2017 15.3.1 today

[image]

The Standard20.csproj looks as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The Core2.csproj looks as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\Standard20.csproj" />
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And the class which I want to use in Core2 project looks very simple:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than just showing a screenshot, it would be much more helpful if you'd provide a minimal example in terms of: a) the two project files; b) a short class in each project; c) a log (as text) of what happens when you use dotnet build.

Comment: Have you installed .NET Core/Standard 2.0 SDK? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core or https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-download.md

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, I have

Comment: Has anyone had this same issue without ReSharper installed? What is different between the project when broken and unbroken? Or maybe our issue is slightly different. We add the reference fine (and can write code which uses the netstandard lib classes), but at runtime it says it can't find the netstandard assembly. I posted this similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343681/reference-netstandard-2-0-project-in-core-2-0-runtime-loading-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the latest [ReSharper 2017.2 release build](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/). It has much better support of VS2017.3 and .NET Core/Standard 2.0

Comment: Upgrading ReSharper from 2017.1.2 to 2017.2 fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that's a VS related issue.
The project compiled and it runs fine, but during the development VS is unable to find a  ClassLibrary1.Class1 from Standard20 project.

[image]

Comment: Could be a ReSharper issue as well. Have you tried closing and reopening the solution and/or Visual Studio?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  Yes, It's a ReSharper issue! Disabling it helped!